# Recalculation the cluster centroids

Tags: python, clustered-index

The first step of k-medoids is that k-centroids/medoids are randomly picked from your dataset (X), how those centroids are recalculated when there are some clusters changing by the updating x1?  **without reclustering**

lets assume that there is a number if round for updating the values of X, e.g. 5 rounds, How are the new centroids picked when the cluster of user 5 is changed to cluster 1? and the cluster of user 0 is changed to cluster 2? (when x1 values are updated) and so on. like this

```
  cluster  user        x1
0        2     0  [0.83200858]
1        4     1  [0.85566274]
2        4     2  [0.85364912]
3        2     3  [0.81536489]
4        1     4  [0.84929932]
5        1     5  [0.83054322]
6        1     6  [0.84899714]
7        2     7  [0.82019115]
8        4     8  [0.86112067]
9        2     9   [0.8312496]
```

how could recalculate the cluster centroids for those clusters that have been affected by the updating? without reclustering the array X

Comment: Where are you confused?  Moving the centroid is explained in any introduction to k-means clustering.  What do you not understand from those explanations?

Comment: Okay -- so what part of that confuses you?  The definition of "centroid" is covered well, and there are many examples of taking the mean of a set of values.  Just where are you stuck?

Comment: @ Prune I stuck in part when there is an update of any value of X, for example, when users 0 or 5 values change, so how to recalculate the centroids in this case ?? i didn't get it how to calculate them !!!!

Comment: A centroid is simply the mean of the cluster.

Comment: @ Prune could you please refer me to an example for my case or any other examples related to my question?